# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to fetch React Data from the API into my website with Axios performing a get request in React (home.jsx) to my Express server file (database.js) where I retrieve info from my Mongo database. When I try to submit my input info on the website, however, I receive this error:

> "AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}".  I was expecting a 401 unauthorized.

I'm expecting a 401 unauthorized. Because here's my home.jsx:

```js
import Navbar from "../../navbar/Navbar";
import Featured from "../../featured/Featured";
import "./home.scss";
import List from "../../list/List";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = ({ type }) => {
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   const getRandomLists =  async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `lists/${type ? "?type=" + type : ""}&${genre ? "&genre=" + genre: ""}`
      );
      
      console.log(res)
      // setLists(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
   };
   getRandomLists();
  }, [type, genre]);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <Navbar />
      <Featured type={type} />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The request I'm trying to make it to is the list route:

```js
//GET
router.get("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
    const typeQuery = req.query.type;
    const genreQuery = req.query.genre;
    let list = [];
    try {
      if (typeQuery) {
        if (genreQuery) {
          list = await List.aggregate([
            { $sample: { size: 10 } },
            { $match: { type: typeQuery, genre: genreQuery } },
          ]);
        } else {
          list = await List.aggregate([
            { $sample: { size: 10 } },
            { $match: { type: typeQuery } },
          ]);
        }
      } else {
        list = await List.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }]);
      }
      res.status(200).json(list);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request in Axios is not structured correctly as you are adding the query parameters after the '/' however query param should only start with "?".Moreover if you are expecting the type to be optional then your request format will again be invalid as query param for genre will start with "&".
The correct format can be as below

```
const res = await axios.get('/lists', {
      params: {
        type: type || undefined, // Only add type parameter if it exists
        genre: genre || undefined // Only add genre parameter if it exists
      }
    });
```